# Can't seem to access .xip.io URL from my iPhone when running Rails app with Pow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iphone, lan, rack-pow, xip.io

I've tried accessing my Rails app running with Pow (4.3) from my iPhone 5 but I'm running into issues...

If I type `my_app.192.168.2.11.xip.io`:

- it runs OK on my development machine (i.e. the machine with the `192.168.2.11` LAN address)
- it doesn't find the host on my iPhone

Of course, the 2 machines are on the same LAN and I tried to access my router's administration web server from my iPhone:

- `192.168.2.1` works: I get to my router's admin web server just fine.
- `192.168.2.1.xip.io` doesn't work! "The host couldn't be found."

Is there anything special to set up for .xip.io addresses to be resolved properly on the iPhone?

EDIT:

I'm working in a café with internet sharing via my iPhone's 4G network. Now .xip.io IP work on my phone. It should have something to do with my LAN configuration then. I have an ASUS router.

Comment: Any chance you're leaving off port 3000 when making the xip.io request from your phone? Any firewalls on your dev machine?

Comment: No. I ran a Jekyll server on my dev machine running on port 3000 and I had the exact same issue: I could access my Jekyll server from my Phone with 192.168.2.11:3000 but couldn't with 192.168.2.11.xip.io:3000 (though 192.168.2.11.xip.io:3000 was working from the dev machine hosting the server)

Comment: I'm working in a café with internet sharing via my iPhone's 4G network. Now .xip.io IP work on my phone. It should have something to do with my LAN configuration then. I have an ASUS router. (edited the question with this comment)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38714136/470749 helped for me.

Comment: Again `xip.io` was working for me on my desktop but not on mobile devices on my wifi. This time, I realized that apparently the problem was that the Signal messaging app for iOS https://signal.org/ was botching the URLs that I sent from Signal desktop to mobile for testing. The URL I'd sent had included `&a={{ad.name}}`, which was just a placeholder for myself (not meant to be used in production), and maybe those braces are invalid characters for a URL. In any case, I could successfully open the `xip.io` link on Signal desktop but not Signal iOS. **The problem had nothing to do with xip.io.**

Comment: Back again, and I'm having a problem that I had in 2018 where xip.io only works from the computer where the site is hosted, and I can't access it from another computer on my LAN: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991630/how-configure-homestead-and-xip-io/38714136#comment84389836_36360304

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to this [post](http://andycroll.com/mac/ruby/xip-io-doesnt-work-on-bt/), I configured my ASUS RT-N56U router to use Google's DNS addresses (i.e. `8.8.8.8`) and it works fine now.

**Edit:** If you are connected via Wifi router, then you need to enable port forwarding to forward a certain port (like 8080) to your laptop.

Comment: Didn't work for me. It seems xip.io addresses sometimes work, and sometimes don't. It's quite random and infuriating!

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem on windows. Flushing dns from command line worked.

```
c:\>ipconfig /flushdns
```

**EDIT**
It works on Chrome,Opera <strike>not on Opera and</strike>  not on Edge.
In Opera you might try add "www." before local ip address.

Comment: adding www worked for me, was driving me crazy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally realized last night (after [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26166205/cant-seem-to-access-xip-io-url-from-my-iphone-when-running-rails-app-with-pow/26267584#comment120345852_26166205)) that https://xip.io/ is currently unavailable.

`sudo wget https://rcw.192.168.1.100.xip.io --no-check-certificate` does still seem to work (if I run that command on the terminal *of the computer that is hosting my site*), which seems to imply that the xip.io service still exists even though their homepage is down.

But I want to access my page from a different device on the LAN, which is what this question is about.

**The fact that the xip.io homepage is down led me to try using an alternative:** https://sslip.io/ (whose creators said they were inspired by xip.io).

Now browsing to https://rcw.192-168-1-100.sslip.io/ from my Win 10 PC works (although their is an issue with the certificate) and shows the page hosted on my Ubuntu laptop.